# Distance convertor issue

Tags: java

I can't obtain exact conversion due to unknown logical error. The program has three input fields. Where the user inputs desired value in desired field. Based on the entry and field of entry the data is converted.

```
package dist;
import java.awt.*;          
import java.awt.event.*;    
import javax.swing.*;   
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DistanceConvertor extends JFrame
{  
    private JLabel KilometreLabel;      
    private JLabel MilesLabel;
private JLabel NauticalMilesLabel;

private JTextField KilometreTF;     
private JTextField MilesTF; 
private JTextField NauticalMilesTF;
private kiloHandler KilometreHandler;
private nauticalHandler NauticalMilesHandler;
private milesHandler MilesHandler;
private static final int WIDTH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 100;   
private static final double OFFSET = 0.0621;
private static final double OFFSET1 = 0.5399568;

public DistanceConvertor()
{
    setTitle("Distance Convertor");
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

    KilometreLabel = new JLabel("Distance in Kilometre:\n ",
                                        SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    MilesLabel = new JLabel("Distance in Miles: ",
                                        SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    NauticalMilesLabel = new JLabel("Distance in Nautical Miles: ",
            SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    KilometreTF = new JTextField(7);
    MilesTF = new JTextField(7);
    NauticalMilesTF = new JTextField(7);
    c.add(KilometreLabel);
    c.add(KilometreTF);
    c.add(MilesLabel);
    c.add(MilesTF);
    c.add(NauticalMilesLabel);
    c.add(NauticalMilesTF);
    KilometreHandler = new kiloHandler();
    MilesHandler = new milesHandler();
    NauticalMilesHandler=new nauticalHandler();

    KilometreTF.addActionListener(KilometreHandler);
    MilesTF.addActionListener(MilesHandler);
    NauticalMilesTF.addActionListener(NauticalMilesHandler);
    setSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private class kiloHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double kilometre, miles,nauticalmiles;

        kilometre =
                Double.parseDouble(KilometreTF.getText());
        nauticalmiles =
                Double.parseDouble(NauticalMilesTF.getText());
        miles = kilometre *  OFFSET;

        MilesTF.setText(String.format("%.4f", miles));
    }
}

private class milesHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double kilometres, miles;
        miles = 
                Double.parseDouble(MilesTF.getText());
        kilometres = (miles / OFFSET) ;
        KilometreTF.setText(String.format("%.4f", kilometres));
    }
}
private class nauticalHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double kilometres, miles,nauticalmiles;
        kilometres = 
                Double.parseDouble(KilometreTF.getText());
         nauticalmiles= (kilometres / OFFSET1) ;
        NauticalMilesTF.setText(String.format("%.4f", nauticalmiles));
    }
}  

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DistanceConvertor DistConv = new DistanceConvertor();
    DistConv.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

When I enter any value in any of the three fields I want to get conversion value. But due to some error I don't get the converted value.

Comment: you may wish to trim down your answer to a minimal working example, most people don't have a lot of time to read through that much code carefully

Comment: The code compiles and runs, but you have not clearly stated your problem. Perhaps you could update your question to provide a specific example: [1] Specify what the user should enter in the input field(s). [2] Specify the expected result for that input.